# Is there a way to add a button to an existing tab or add a new tab in the file explorer ribbon?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-controls, customization, ribbon

I'm trying add a button or tab to the default Windows 10 file explorer ribbon.

I've tried looking up different solutions but I've only come up with things for MS Office which not what I'm trying to add to. I've included a screenshot to explain where I'd like to add the button/tab.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this even possible in C# and Visual Studio? Are there other solutions for this that require other tools/languages?

EDIT: The suggested answer adds a panel to either side of the window. What I'm looking to do is change the ribbon at the top of the window by either adding a button or tab to the existing tabs

Comment: @TaW could you please have a look again? The OP clarified his question, not sure if the duplicate answers this ... (from reopen votes queue)

Comment: Well the answer and all the comments should make it clear that this will be even harder. But I have reopened it; maybe somebody can help.. - As it stands the question is way too broad though, so it should soon be closed again.